# Regex for converting emails to hyperlinks, but not if already hyperlinks, and URLS to hyperlinks missing trailing slash

Tags: c#, regex, email

I have a RegEx to convert emails to hyperlinks but if the email is already a hyperlink it is still converting it which breaks it. I have the following code:

```
string regex = @"([&;a-zA-Z_0-9.-]+\@[a-zA-Z_0-9.-]+\.\w+)";
```

I need to add something to it to check for  at the end. I think I need a negative lookahead - `?!&lt;/a&gt;` - or something?

Also I have another Regex that converts URLs to hyperlinks but if the URL ends in a slash it is not including that in the hyperlink. Here's my code:

```
var reg = new Regex(@"(?<!<\s*(?:a|img)\b[^<]*)(\b((http|https)://|www\.)[^ <]+\b)");
```

How do I include trailing slashes?

Comment: I have edited my answer for .net.au, etc and to handle trailing slash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the URL for:

```
test@test.net
```

is:

```
<a href="mailto:test@test.net">test@test.net</a>
```

**Edit**: If you don't want to convert existing href and handle addresses such as test@test.net.au then you could do:

```
([&;a-zA-Z_0-9.-]+\@[a-zA-Z_0-9.-]+\.\w+)(?!([\w.]+)*(?:</a>|">))
```

Basically it says don't match the email address if it is followed by some combination of `.` and word characters and then `</a>` or `">`. I have not html encoded for readability.

You were on the right track with your negative lookahead, but you need the `\w*` otherwise it would match test@test.ne because this is followed by `t` rather than `</a>`

**Update**

Just saw the second part. For the trailing slash, could you just append `/?`:

```
(?<!<\s*(?:a|img)\b[^<]*)(\b((http|https)://|www\.)[^ <]+\b/?)
```

That means 0 or 1 trailing slash.

Comment: Thank you... But this works for test@test.net but not test@test.net.au! Are you able to help with the second part of my question too?

Comment: @John See the edit to handle test@test.net.au and the update to handle the trailing slash.

Comment: Thank you very much. Solves all my problems.